# React native - How to know the height of the view after all children view have been finished rendering?

Tags: react-native, webview, view, rendering, react-native-render-html

I'm using `react-native-render-html` to render HTML article.

The goal is to scroll to next element (like Comment section, Next article...) after the article has finished the rendering.

But since it loads remote images, the height of the view depends on HTML elements, and the loading time depends on the network speed ...

Is there any method to know exact height of the view after finish rendering?

Comment: To have a non-variable height, you would need every `img` to have `width` and `height` attributes set. That way, `react-native-render-html` will print a placeholder of the appropriate dimensions prior to fetching the images.

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph even with static img width , height, they have to be scaled to be fit with smartphone screen. size will be recalculated. Parent view may contain many child views like (table, list) impact by css, couldn't find the way to calculate all of them.